# Remove Duplicate Entries of 'Multicolumn'-List with LINQ

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, linq, duplicates

I do have 2 lists of the same user-defined type. Each consisting of: ID, TimesTested, varA, varB.

The lists need to be joined and then saved to a local file. Duplicate entries need to be removed.

The problem is that i can not just search for the ID and check if it already there, because i always need to keep the entry where 'TimesTested' has the higher value.

I really dont want to loop thru both lists for and back and check for the values manually. So i am thinking of LINQ.

Is it possible to do the following if i have given:

```
4, 16, X, Y
4, 19, X, Y
```

to only keep the second row? (using LINQ, or in another 'smart' way)

if yes, could u please explain me how?

---

strangely it works when i load the values the first time from the local file. 
also the first saving seems to work smoothly... but as soon as i try to write the list a second time to the file.. i get the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type "WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,mcq_gui.clsEvaluation+History+EvaluationQuestionData],mcq_gui.clsEvaluation+History+EvaluationQuestionData]" to type Typ "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[mcq_gui.clsEvaluation+History+EvaluationQuestionData]"
```

this is the code i am using:

```
Friend Shared Function GetNewerEvalQs(list1 As List(Of EvaluationQuestionData), list2 As List(Of EvaluationQuestionData)) As List(Of EvaluationQuestionData)
        Dim uniques As New List(Of EvaluationQuestionData)
        Try
            If list1.Count > 0 And list2.Count > 0 Then
                uniques = list1.Concat(list2).GroupBy(Function(t) t.ID).[Select](Function(g) g.OrderByDescending(Function(t) t.TimesTested).First())
            Else
                If list1.Count > 0 Then
                    Return list1
                ElseIf list2.Count > 0 Then
                    Return list2
                Else
                    Return Nothing
                End If
            End If

            Return uniques
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.Message)
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way, using `Enumerable.GroupBy` and then select the highest according to `TimesTested`.

```
var uniques = list1.Concat(list2)
    .GroupBy(t => t.ID)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(t => t.TimesTested).First());
```

**Edit** ... or in VB.NET (sorry, i didn 't see the tag first) and with your method:

```
Friend Shared Function GetNewerEvalQs(list1 As List(Of EvaluationQuestionData), list2 As List(Of EvaluationQuestionData)) As List(Of EvaluationQuestionData)
    list1 = If(list1 Is Nothing, New List(Of EvaluationQuestionData), list1)
    list2 = If(list2 Is Nothing, New List(Of EvaluationQuestionData), list2)
    If Math.Max(list1.Count, list2.Count) = 0 Then Throw New ArgumentException("One of both lists must contain data")

    Dim newUniqueData = list1.Concat(list2).
        OrderByDescending(Function(eqd) eqd.TimeTested).
        GroupBy(Function(eqd) eqd.ID).
        Select(Function(g) g.First()).
        ToList()
    Return newUniqueData
End Function
```